# fvm flutter pub get from Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fvm

I am using fvm (Flutter Version Management) for Flutter.

One of the small issues I have is that I was used to clicking the Pub Get button at the top of the pubspec.yaml.

However this runs *flutter pub get* and not *fvm flutter pub get*. So now I have to rely on the command line.

Can someone suggest a workaround so that the button will run fvm flutter pub get?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can Change the Flutter SDK path in Android Studio Perferences.

You can select the version from Perferences. Search Flutter settings. You must have install Flutter plugin, so change the setting Flutter SDK path to your version like this: xxx/project/.fvm/flutter_sdk

your project have the folder `.fvm` after execute the command `fvm use x.y.z -f` before. specify the sdk path to `your project .fvm/flutter_sdk` absolute path, for example `/Users/xxx/project/.fvm/flutter_sdk`

for more details to view offical website [fvm](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration/#android-studio).